# Can someone explain to me the mathematics behind this code which calculates the "minimum cosine distance"?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose we have two equal sized arrays of vectors
$$
array_1 = \{ (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ... , (x_n, y_n) \}\\
array_2 = \{ (x_1', y_1'), (x_2', y_2'), ... , (x_n', y_n') \}
$$

What the code does is to accumulate the dot products of each corresponding vectors:
$$dots = (x_1\times x_1' + y_1\times y_1') + (x_2\times x_2' + y_2\times y_2') + ... $$
and also accumulate the determinant/cross products of each corresponding vectors:
$$crosses = (x_1\times y_1' - y_1\times x_1') + (x_2\times y_2' - y_2\times x_2') + ... $$

Eventually after some more manipulation they return the $$\arccos(\sqrt{dots^2 + crosses^2})$$

My question is how does this mathematical procedure give us the distance that these vectors have?
(the smaller the distance, the more similar the two arrays of vectors.)
**I don't understand how taking the *norm of the dots and crosses* will give an indicator of similarity/dissimilarity.** Am I missing/misunderstanding something?

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/gesture/GestureUtils.java#GestureUtils.minimumCosineDistance%28float[]%2Cfloat[]%2Cint%29

This is my edited version of their code to make things easier to understand.

```
public static float CosineDistance(float[] vector1, float[] vector2) {
    final int len = vector1.length;
    float dots = 0;
    float crosses = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        dots += vector1[i] * vector2[i] + vector1[i + 1] * vector2[i + 1];
        crosses += vector1[i] * vector2[i + 1] - vector1[i + 1] * vector2[i];
    }
    if (dots != 0) {
        final float tan = crosses/dots;
        final double angle = Math.atan(tan);
        final double cosine = Math.cos(angle);
        final double sine = cosine * tan;
        return (float) (dots * cosine + crosses * sine); //Norm
    } else {
        return (float) -1;
    }
}
```

EDIT (only if you want to know about the original code):

My modified code works well, and it can recognize close matches. **What I want to understand is the mathematics behind the code**.

My apologies if this is starting to sound more code than mathematics, but since I was asked to explain what numOrientations was, here is the background.

At [line 66](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/gesture/GestureStore.java#GestureStore),

```
// ORIENTATION_SENSITIVE and ORIENTATION_INVARIANT are only for SEQUENCE_SENSITIVE gestures
public static final int ORIENTATION_INVARIANT = 1;
// at most 2 directions can be recognized
public static final int ORIENTATION_SENSITIVE = 2;
// at most 4 directions can be recognized
static final int ORIENTATION_SENSITIVE_4 = 4;
// at most 8 directions can be recognized
static final int ORIENTATION_SENSITIVE_8 = 8;
```

Basically, I set `mOrientationStyle = ORIENTATION_INVARIANT`

This is later passed into `mClassifier.classify(mSequenceType, mOrientationStyle, instance.vector);` **line 139**

and then into `GestureUtils.minimumCosineDistance(sample.vector, vector, mOrientationStyle);` in the instanceLearner class

But since I am using `ORIENTATION_INVARIANT` in my code, I believe that `numOrientations` can be safely ignored in the original minimumCosineDistance code. (hence I removed that section in my code.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

Comment: I read that already, but am still confused. Do you mean that the sum of dots is the numerator, and the sum of crosses is the denominator in http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/f/3/6/f369863aa2814d6e283f859986a1574d.png

Comment: It seems that your edited function is not the same as the function "cosineDistance" in the link.

Comment: Ya I renamed some variables (for easier understanding), and removed the "numOrientations" (which I wasn't using), and I also removed the arcCos term since -1 <= (dots * cosine + crosses * sine) <= 1 could be used just as well for the indication of distance.

Comment: Could you explain what does "numOrientations" mean? It's important here.

Comment: @echo edited to explain what numOrientations mean. But I set it to equals 1, so it becomes redundant in the original code.

Comment: @user245964 Just another question, what's the content in two input vectors? It's my first time to see such a function. I'm also feel a little confused. Maybe it has some application context.

Comment: @echo Not enough rep to move discussion to chat, so anyway, the input vector is an array of floats. vector[0]->x_0, vector[1]->y_0, vector[2]->x_1, vector[3]->y_1 ... vector[2*n]->x_n, vector[2*n+1]->y_n. They are comparing two input arrays. Each array consists of several 2D-vectors (x, y).